# Get Facebook user email id for microsoft chatbot

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-chatbot

I need to create chat bot which will be published in Facebook. When user interact with my bot i need their name and email id from Facebook.

I know Facebook have user profile api for getting user details like First name and last name but i need Email id also. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile

Is there any way i can get email id of facebook user who interact with my bot.

I have seen this post but still i could not find way for getting email id
[How to get the Facebook email of a user for a bot using bot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673084/how-to-get-the-facebook-email-of-a-user-for-a-bot-using-bot-framework)

I am using Microsoft bot framework v4.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam

Comment: there is an answer in the other thread already, and it seems to be up to date.

Comment: There is no answer there, if you see my description i have also mentioned about the other post you are referring.

Comment: there IS an answer in the duplicate thread. with 3 upvotes.

Comment: yes i have seen this, yet it says Facebook does not give email ids. I have seen this. but i want to know if there is any way to do it. though it is very old post, i thought, someone might have answer.

Comment: so is there any question that is not solved by the answer in the duplicate thread?

Comment: luschn thanks for your response, really appreciated. I want to get response for my query.

Comment: the answer in the duplicate thread answers your question, there´s really nothing else to add.