# Get registered Facebook email of a user in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger

Is there a way to automatically get the registered facebook email of a user in Botframework v4? Currently i can get it by prompting the user like the code below. Are there other ways that does not need to prompt the user? Thanks!

```
Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
reply.Text = "What is your Email address?";
reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    quick_replies = new object[]
    {
        new
        {
            content_type = "user_email",
        },
    },
});
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(EmailPromptId, new PromptOptions { Prompt = reply }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API, how to get users email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Facebook email of a user for a bot using bot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673084/how-to-get-the-facebook-email-of-a-user-for-a-bot-using-bot-framework)

Comment: Those answer are from 2016 so i thought maybe something changed.